# Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts' when installing quarkus in sdkman

Tags: java, quarkus, sdkman

I am using sdkman since I have to work with different versions of java. Using sdkman I installed quarkus version 2.11.1, however whenever I do every command related to quarkus like:

```
quarkus --version
```

it doesn't matter if I write anything with quarkus. eg quarkus --help, or something nonsense like quarkus --woof or just quarkus

I receive always the same error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I saw several examples related to this error here in Stackoverflow but the thing is that java is working well and it doesn't matter if I write java --version or java -version, the result works well

```
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.6.10.1 (build 17.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Has anyone had somehow experience in this situation? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`AggressiveOpts` is a deprecated JDK argument that was removed in JDK 13. It makes sense that you see that message when using JDK 17.

There is some configuration in your system still using that removed argument. It may be the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`, some docker configuration or somewhere else.